# Shadows on transparent background not appearing with shadow catcher

Tags: rendering, transparency, shadows

I am rendering a png image with a plane transparent background being used a shadow catcher. However, the shadows are not appearing in the png. I have made sure that the shadow catcher is turned on in the visibility settings of the lights.

For reference, the first image is one rendered on a transparent background then placed on a white background in photoshop. The second image is a direct render from blender with the plane not acting as a shadow catcher.

Can anyone figure out why this is happening?

Thanks,

[image: Image rendered with transparent background]

[image: Image without shadow catcher]

Comment: _"...the shadow catcher is turned on in the visibility settings of the lights"_? The plane below the drops(? stones?) needs to be set to _Shadow Catcher_, not the lights.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the reply. Yes, I meant to say that in addition to the plane being set to shadow catcher, the lights have also been set. Thanks

Comment: Oh, you do not mean a light in the scene, but in the _View Layer Properties_ under _Passes_ > _Light_ you have enabled _Shadow Catcher_? Blender has a lot of settings, it is always helpful to explain precisely what you did or even better: show the settings you are talking about. Because if you mean the _Passes_, this enables a _Shadow Catcher_ output in the _Compositor_, so you can use the shadow in post processing. In this case it is not directly visible in the render. I've explained that in my answer here: [Changes of shadows color](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294652/)